# to replace " " with &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, whitespace, html-entities

this is my javascript code:

```
mystring = "this is sample";
nestring = mystring.replace(/ /g,"&nbsp;");
```

I need nestring ouput "this is sample".

but with the code above, `nestring = "this&nbsp;is&nbsp;sample"`
how can I replace space(`&#x20;`) with &nbsp(`&#xA0;`)?
Many thanks!

---

re:
I embed svg in html. But ie, chrome do not support xml:space=preserve, firefox does. By replace " " with &nbsp, multiple " " will not condense to one " ".

Comment: Looks fine for me.. @ http://jsfiddle.net/vyB7x/

Comment: do you mean that you want to SEE the &nbsp; code? and not the space itself? you could replace with &amp;nbsp;

Comment: What "doesn't work" and "how are you displaying the string"?

Comment: Not sure what you want either? Your example should work fine. Though you might want to specify whitespace more appropriately: mystring.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;");

Comment: Where do you want the output to appear? On web page? Alert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Unicode:

```
nestring = mystring.replace(/ /g, "\u00a0");
```

But your example did exactly what you told it to.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the characters with character code 32 (0x20) with character with character code 160 (0xA0), you can use the `fromCharCode` method to create the string to replace with:

```
nestring = mystring.replace(/ /g, String.fromCharCode(160));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, but if you are writing the result to the document you will only see the spaces because they are HTML encoded.

If you `alert(nestring);` you will see that the spaces are replaced.