# Convert string in Unicode

Tags: html, unicode, joomla

I want to covert a simple string in Unicode like this:

```
simple string =  `Pritesh & Nilesh is a good friend.`
```

And I want to get in this form:

```
string =  `Pritesh&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Nilesh&nbsp;is&nbsp;good&nbsp;friend.`
```

I want to convert to this type of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use htmlentities() in php. This replaces all special html characters with their &xxxx; symbols. The PHP manual page is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) for more info. For your example this would be:

```
$string = "Pritesh & Nilesh is good friend.";
$string = htmlentities($string, ENT_HTML5);
```

However this won't replace your spaces with line-breaks as these are considered standard html character and shouldn't be necessary in 99.9% of cases anyway. However if really need this you can use either php for this:

```
$string = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $string);
```

Or javascript:

```
var myString= $string;
myString.replace(/ /g,'&nbsp;');
```

as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084613/to-replace-with-nbsp)

Comment: Note that `ENT_HTML5` is only for PHP 5.4+

Answer (score 3):

You can try `htmlentities` like this

```
$text= "Pritesh & Nilesh is good friend.";

$text2=htmlentities($text); //for converting all special character in string

$text3=str_ireplace(' ','&nbsp;',$text2); //for removing the white space
```

for more info go to this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)